# is <CLLocationManagerDelegate> necessary to get the users location?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, delegates, core-location

the file that I need the users information in already has a -flipsideViewControllerDelegate-, so Is there a way that I can get the users location coordinates without using the CLLocationManagerDelegate thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`-[CLLocationManager location]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW10) to get the most recently returned location, but I'd imagine that you'd still have to have the location manager updating the location.

However, by using the `location` property, you're switching from an interrupt-driven mechanism (an asynchronous callback) to a polling mechanism.  The former is almost always much more efficient for getting continuous updates.

Comment: I dont need continuous updates at the moment, so a polling mechanism would probably be better. However, do i need to make a different .h/.m filegroup to get the location manager to update the location? or could I have it done within my mainViewController (assuming that the mainViewController still has a -FlipSideViewDelegate- in the header file)?

Comment: There's no need for a different .h/.m "filegroup", since a `CLLocationManager` can be stored in an instance variable...

Comment: ok. Seems like this is the solution I want, so I'll put your answer as "The" answer.

Answer (score 0):

for iOS 4.x, location can be found using , MKMapView delegates as well.